# how to get the session ID in .net and insert it in a table when user loggin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, logging, insert

how to get the session ID in .net and insert it in a table when user loggin?

I cant get the value, and I need to get the value and put into a variable because i need to insert in a table.

Comment: what do you mean? HTTP Session? Maybe share some code or some more information

Comment: Please check out [ask] and provide as many details as you can about the problem and the application you are building as well as some code as already mentioned. E.g.: how is a session defined/created in your application?